# How to add psycopg2 to python in windows?

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I need to connect to PostgreSQL in a python class, but I can't add psycopg2 to python34

```
import psycopg2
```

I tried to run a command on the cmd but it didn't work.

Comment: Next time please be more specific about any error messages you get and your configuration (for example, where the module is actually installed, as you believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download psycopg2 from GitHub https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows

copy psycopg2 folder and paste it to yo

> C:\Python34\Lib

Download PyCharm python editor for good